# Can't connect to the　http://169.254.169.254/ from the container of AWS_VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have task difinition which uses `AWS_VPC` mode.

My enviroment is like this,

```
EC2(on private with nat subnet) -> ECS Service -> Container(with AWS_VPC)
```

However, from Container, can't connect to the `http://169.254.169.254` to get the EC2 information.

If I changed the mode to `HOST`, it can connect to the `http://169.254.169.254`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [ECS Task Metadata Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4.html) from within your containers, instead of trying to use the EC2 Instance Metadata Endpoint.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can access the metadata Endpoint from the container , endpoint is stored in environment variable.

Comment: I can access the `ECS Task Metadata Endpoint`, however what I want to is EC2 instance data such as `instance-id`,`instance-type`. Is it possible?

Comment: It might be another problem, I made the another article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76538787/how-to-get-the-instance-information-in-the-container-wit-aws-vpc-mode